# unable to create term document matrix in python(jupyter)

Tags: python, text-mining

While running the following code in jupyter to create term document matrix, I'm getting an error saying nameerror: name 'textmining' not defined.

The code is as below:

```
#create term document matrix
tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix(post_corpus)

for i in post_corpus:
    #print(i)
    tdm.add_doc(i)

NameError: name 'textmining' is not defined
```

I checked whether textmining function is installed or not by running this code:

```
!pip install textmining
```

and after running, the output is:

Requirement already satisfied: textmining in c:\users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: stemming in c:\users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.1)

What should I do counter the name error occurring during the creation of term document matrix? Is there any alternate way of creating this term document matrix?

Comment: Did you import it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you import?

```
import textmining

tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
for post in post_corpus:
    tdm.add_doc(post)
```

Update:08-11-2018 
We can use scikit-learn to get the same results

Requirements:

```
pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn pandas
```

After installing:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus =['John and Bob are brothers.'
    ,'John went to the store. The store was closed.'
    ,'Bob went to the store too.',]


vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

df= pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I imported textmining from jupyter using     ! pip install textmining

Comment: !pip install packages_name only installs the package. After installing, you need to import package_name ;)

Comment: I imported textmining using import textmining its showing errror, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stemmer'

Comment: You need to pip install stemming :) What you are trying to do is similar to CountVectorizer in Scikit-learn. I have updated my answer.